# Matplotlib kills kernel on Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

[image: Screenshot of error]

Hi, I'm taking a machine learning course on udemy and im trying to run the following:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The issue is that once I run this, it kills the kernel and the message shown in the picture is the only thing that comes out.

I'm new to this and I just want to move forward with the course but this is holding me back.

TIA

Comment: `%matplotlib inline` should already include `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. What happens when you run each of those commands separately? Which one is triggering the restart? Does this happen with a freshly-loaded kernel and an empty Jupyter notebook?

Comment: the import line is what causes it, and yes even with a new notebook it happens

Comment: Does your code otherwise work fine without the import statement, even if it uses `plt`?

Comment: Still, even if it does, I would recommend force uninstalling and reinstalling `matplotlib`.

Comment: No, it doesnt. I get an error code saying "plt" is not defined

Comment: How can i do the uninstalling and installing?

Comment: `pip install --force-reinstall matplotlib` should do the trick.

Comment: Just did it and it still happens

Comment: Darn. How familiar are you with the command line (Terminal.app)? Have you configured a `matplotlibrc` file or `jupyter_config.py` or any of those?

Comment: uhhh nope. I just installed python a 3 and anaconda and thats it. Chcecked on anaconda and matplotlib is installed. I can work with the command line, i would just need the steps and commands and I would be able to do it

Comment: OK, make sure you've completely closed out of your Jupyter notebooks and shut down all the running kernels. Then, in Terminal, type `cd` and hit Enter. Next, enter each of these commands one at a time, *exactly* as they are here: 1) `rm -rf .matplotlib` 2) `rm -rf .ipython` 3) `rm -rf .jupyter` You may get errors after some of them saying it doesn't exist, you may not. Then, restart your Jupyter notebook and see if the behavior still happens.

Comment: Are you using an anaconda distribution?

Comment: Quick update. I had to completely uninstall all the anaconda files and software and reinstall it. I installed the terminal version of anaconda instead of the graphic one and everything works fine now. Thanks yall.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved for me by running `conda install freetype=2.10.4`, as reported on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/21513)