# Importing torch makes matplotlib kill kernel

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch, anaconda, jupyter

This code kills the kernel when executing the lineplot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time

import torch

sns.lineplot(x=np.arange(1, 10), y=np.arange(1, 10))
plt.show()
```

But this one doesn't:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time

sns.lineplot(x=np.arange(1, 10), y=np.arange(1, 10))
plt.show()
```

The same behavior is seen using plt.plot(x, y).
I'm using a conda environment on windows 10 and I've tried running a jupyter notebook cell, my environment is this:
python=3.10.9
and this is my pip list return:

```
alabaster                     0.7.12
anaconda-client               1.11.2
anaconda-navigator            2.4.0
anaconda-project              0.11.1
anyio                         3.5.0
appdirs                       1.4.4
argon2-cffi                   21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings          21.2.0
arrow                         1.2.3
astroid                       2.14.2
astropy                       5.1
asttokens                     2.0.5
atomicwrites                  1.4.0
attrs                         22.1.0
Automat                       20.2.0
autopep8                      1.6.0
Babel                         2.11.0
backcall                      0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache 1.6.4
backports.tempfile            1.0
backports.weakref             1.0.post1
bcrypt                        3.2.0
beautifulsoup4                4.11.1
binaryornot                   0.4.4
black                         22.6.0
bleach                        4.1.0
bokeh                         2.4.3
boltons                       23.0.0
Bottleneck                    1.3.5
brotlipy                      0.7.0
certifi                       2022.12.7
cffi                          1.15.1
chardet                       4.0.0
charset-normalizer            2.0.4
click                         8.0.4
cloudpickle                   2.0.0
clyent                        1.2.2
colorama                      0.4.6
colorcet                      3.0.1
comm                          0.1.2
conda                         23.3.1
conda-build                   3.24.0
conda-content-trust           0.1.3
conda-pack                    0.6.0
conda-package-handling        2.0.2
conda_package_streaming       0.7.0
conda-repo-cli                1.0.41
conda-token                   0.4.0
conda-verify                  3.4.2
constantly                    15.1.0
contourpy                     1.0.5
cookiecutter                  1.7.3
cryptography                  39.0.1
cssselect                     1.1.0
cycler                        0.11.0
cytoolz                       0.12.0
daal4py                       2023.0.2
dask                          2022.7.0
datashader                    0.14.4
datashape                     0.5.4
debugpy                       1.5.1
decorator                     5.1.1
defusedxml                    0.7.1
diff-match-patch              20200713
dill                          0.3.6
distributed                   2022.7.0
docstring-to-markdown         0.11
docutils                      0.18.1
entrypoints                   0.4
et-xmlfile                    1.1.0
executing                     0.8.3
fastjsonschema                2.16.2
filelock                      3.9.0
flake8                        6.0.0
Flask                         2.2.2
flit_core                     3.6.0
fonttools                     4.25.0
fsspec                        2022.11.0
future                        0.18.3
gensim                        4.3.0
glob2                         0.7
greenlet                      2.0.1
h5py                          3.7.0
HeapDict                      1.0.1
holoviews                     1.15.4
huggingface-hub               0.10.1
hvplot                        0.8.2
hyperlink                     21.0.0
idna                          3.4
imagecodecs                   2021.8.26
imageio                       2.26.0
imagesize                     1.4.1
imbalanced-learn              0.10.1
importlib-metadata            4.11.3
incremental                   21.3.0
inflection                    0.5.1
iniconfig                     1.1.1
intake                        0.6.7
intervaltree                  3.1.0
ipykernel                     6.19.2
ipython                       8.10.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
ipywidgets                    7.6.5
isort                         5.9.3
itemadapter                   0.3.0
itemloaders                   1.0.4
itsdangerous                  2.0.1
jedi                          0.18.1
jellyfish                     0.9.0
Jinja2                        3.1.2
jinja2-time                   0.2.0
jmespath                      0.10.0
joblib                        1.1.1
json5                         0.9.6
jsonpatch                     1.32
jsonpointer                   2.1
jsonschema                    4.17.3
jupyter                       1.0.0
jupyter_client                7.3.4
jupyter-console               6.6.2
jupyter_core                  5.2.0
jupyter-server                1.23.4
jupyterlab                    3.5.3
jupyterlab-pygments           0.1.2
jupyterlab_server             2.19.0
jupyterlab-widgets            1.0.0
keyring                       23.4.0
kiwisolver                    1.4.4
lazy-object-proxy             1.6.0
libarchive-c                  2.9
llvmlite                      0.39.1
locket                        1.0.0
lxml                          4.9.1
lz4                           3.1.3
Markdown                      3.4.1
MarkupSafe                    2.1.1
matplotlib                    3.7.0
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
mccabe                        0.7.0
menuinst                      1.4.19
mistune                       0.8.4
mkl-fft                       1.3.1
mkl-random                    1.2.2
mkl-service                   2.4.0
mock                          4.0.3
mpmath                        1.2.1
msgpack                       1.0.3
multipledispatch              0.6.0
munkres                       1.1.4
mypy-extensions               0.4.3
navigator-updater             0.3.0
nbclassic                     0.5.2
nbclient                      0.5.13
nbconvert                     6.5.4
nbformat                      5.7.0
nest-asyncio                  1.5.6
networkx                      2.8.4
nltk                          3.7
notebook                      6.5.2
notebook_shim                 0.2.2
numba                         0.56.4
numexpr                       2.8.4
numpy                         1.23.5
numpydoc                      1.5.0
openpyxl                      3.0.10
packaging                     22.0
pandas                        1.5.3
pandocfilters                 1.5.0
panel                         0.14.3
param                         1.12.3
paramiko                      2.8.1
parsel                        1.6.0
parso                         0.8.3
partd                         1.2.0
pathlib                       1.0.1
pathspec                      0.10.3
patsy                         0.5.3
pep8                          1.7.1
pexpect                       4.8.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        9.4.0
pip                           22.3.1
pkginfo                       1.9.6
platformdirs                  2.5.2
plotly                        5.9.0
pluggy                        1.0.0
ply                           3.11
pooch                         1.4.0
poyo                          0.5.0
prometheus-client             0.14.1
prompt-toolkit                3.0.36
Protego                       0.1.16
psutil                        5.9.0
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
pure-eval                     0.2.2
py                            1.11.0
pyasn1                        0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                0.2.8
pycodestyle                   2.10.0
pycosat                       0.6.4
pycparser                     2.21
pyct                          0.5.0
pycurl                        7.45.1
PyDispatcher                  2.0.5
pydocstyle                    6.3.0
pyerfa                        2.0.0
pyflakes                      3.0.1
Pygments                      2.11.2
PyHamcrest                    2.0.2
PyJWT                         2.4.0
pylint                        2.16.2
pylint-venv                   2.3.0
pyls-spyder                   0.4.0
PyNaCl                        1.5.0
pyodbc                        4.0.34
pyOpenSSL                     23.0.0
pyparsing                     3.0.9
PyQt5                         5.15.7
PyQt5-sip                     12.11.0
PyQtWebEngine                 5.15.4
pyrsistent                    0.18.0
PySocks                       1.7.1
pytest                        7.1.2
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-lsp-black              1.2.1
python-lsp-jsonrpc            1.0.0
python-lsp-server             1.7.1
python-slugify                5.0.2
python-snappy                 0.6.1
pytoolconfig                  1.2.5
pytz                          2022.7
pyviz-comms                   2.0.2
PyWavelets                    1.4.1
pywin32                       305.1
pywin32-ctypes                0.2.0
pywinpty                      2.0.10
PyYAML                        6.0
pyzmq                         23.2.0
QDarkStyle                    3.0.2
qstylizer                     0.2.2
QtAwesome                     1.2.2
qtconsole                     5.4.0
QtPy                          2.2.0
queuelib                      1.5.0
regex                         2022.7.9
requests                      2.28.1
requests-file                 1.5.1
requests-toolbelt             0.9.1
rope                          1.7.0
Rtree                         1.0.1
ruamel.yaml                   0.17.21
ruamel.yaml.clib              0.2.6
ruamel-yaml-conda             0.17.21
scikit-image                  0.19.3
scikit-learn                  1.2.1
scikit-learn-intelex          20230228.214818
scipy                         1.10.0
Scrapy                        2.8.0
seaborn                       0.12.2
Send2Trash                    1.8.0
service-identity              18.1.0
setuptools                    65.6.3
sip                           6.6.2
six                           1.16.0
sklearn                       0.0.post5
smart-open                    5.2.1
sniffio                       1.2.0
snowballstemmer               2.2.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
soupsieve                     2.3.2.post1
Sphinx                        5.0.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5
spyder                        5.4.1
spyder-kernels                2.4.1
SQLAlchemy                    1.4.39
stack-data                    0.2.0
statsmodels                   0.13.5
sympy                         1.11.1
tables                        3.7.0
tabulate                      0.8.10
TBB                           0.2
tblib                         1.7.0
tenacity                      8.0.1
terminado                     0.17.1
text-unidecode                1.3
textdistance                  4.2.1
threadpoolctl                 2.2.0
three-merge                   0.1.1
tifffile                      2021.7.2
tinycss2                      1.2.1
tldextract                    3.2.0
tokenizers                    0.11.4
toml                          0.10.2
tomli                         2.0.1
tomlkit                       0.11.1
toolz                         0.12.0
torch                         2.0.1+cu118
torchaudio                    2.0.2+cu118
torchvision                   0.15.2+cu118
tornado                       6.1
tqdm                          4.64.1
traitlets                     5.7.1
transformers                  4.24.0
Twisted                       22.2.0
twisted-iocpsupport           1.0.2
typing_extensions             4.4.0
ujson                         5.4.0
Unidecode                     1.2.0
urllib3                       1.26.14
w3lib                         1.21.0
watchdog                      2.1.6
wcwidth                       0.2.5
webencodings                  0.5.1
websocket-client              0.58.0
Werkzeug                      2.2.2
whatthepatch                  1.0.2
wheel                         0.38.4
widgetsnbextension            3.5.2
win-inet-pton                 1.1.0
wincertstore                  0.2
wrapt                         1.14.1
xarray                        2022.11.0
xlwings                       0.29.1
yapf                          0.31.0
zict                          2.1.0
zipp                          3.11.0
zope.interface                5.4.0
zstandard                     0.19.0
```

This is the 3rd environment i try. I've built 2 very similar environments before, and had the same issue, one was python 3.8 and the other one was python 3.9, I thought I might have screwed my anaconda instalation and even hard reinstalled it all. I still have the same problem, which is very weird to me, never seen anything like this.

I need to use graphs AND torch haha, and i don't seem to be able to do it anymore.

I've tried every solution proposed here: [Matplotlib kills kernel on Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69067429/matplotlib-kills-kernel-on-jupyter)

But none of them worked.

My procedure to build my environment was exactly this one:

```
conda create -n env_name
conda activate env_name
pip install numpy pandas sklearn jupyter matplotlib seaborn
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
```

The previous two envs were the same procedure, except for a python=version in the create command.

I really don't know what else I can do.

Apart from that, the environment works perfectly, I can use torch and cuda normally, and separately I can also use matplotlib and seaborn normally. I just can't use them both on the same code for some reason. The kernel simply dies, no memory usage, no explanation, just dies.

Comment: If you are using anaconda, do not use pip to install packages available in the conda ecosystem. At the Anaconda prompt conda install package. Review https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html; look for the specific package in Anaconda, and review its install instructions

Comment: I've used pip to install on anaconda environments for many years, never had any problem because of that, but might as well try using only conda install and see if it solves my problem.

Comment: As an FYI packages installed from Anaconda are precompiled, I don’t think that’s the case with pip.

Comment: There is a specific set of instructions for installing Jupiter in a secondary environment. Jupiter runs from the primary environment or base, but then you have to install ipykernel in subsequent environments and then, when you open Jupiter, all of her environments will show up in the drop-down. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63770126/7758804